# AngularJS + Webpack works on development mode but not on production mode

Tags: angularjs, webpack, bundle

I am running webpack-dev-server in development and it serves my project without any problem. If I build the project using `mode: "development"` in the webpack config, there not any problems at all.
But when I run the webpack with `mode: "production"` it doesn't work.

This is my webpack configs (common, dev and prod):

```
// webpack.common.js

const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

function resolvePath(dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '../', dir);
}

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {
  target: "web",
  entry: {
    vendors: './src/assets/vendors.js',
    bundle: './src/bin/www'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: './index.html',
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  output: {
    path: resolvePath('dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: "jQuery",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            attrs: [':data-src']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg|jpg|jpeg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'media/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },

    ],
  },
};

// webpack.dev.js
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  }
});

// webpack.prod.js
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production'
});
```

The build is working but when I am trying to run the code in the browser, using http-server, I can the next error - only when build for production, not development! (I am using AngularJS 1.7.2):

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=taxi4you-console&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.7.2%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3De%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.7.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A168%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.7.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A215%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.7.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A433)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.7.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A44%3A171)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.7.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A44%3A256)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.7.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A407)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.7.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A43%3A19%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.7.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A8%3A76)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.7.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A308)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20hb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.7.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A401)
>
> ```
>     at angular.js:99
>     at angular.js:5027
>     at q (angular.js:387)
>     at g (angular.js:4987)
>     at hb (angular.js:4904)
>     at c (angular.js:1936)
>     at Vc (angular.js:1957)
>     at ye (angular.js:1842)
>     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:35431)
>     at l (jquery.min.js:2)
> ```

I got warning from webpack that my bundle is too large. Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that your minification process is minifying the DI names for angular objects. When this happens and angularjs tries to load an injected object, it is not able to track down the dependencies since the names have been mangled.

In order to avoid this, you should use the [babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate](https://github.com/schmod/babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate) plugin. This plugin ensures that your `ngInject` statements are not mangled.